# Does CNAME (Canonical Name record) override A (address record)?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address, cname-record, address

If I have an address record setup as follows...

```
www.mywebsite.com  111.1.1.1
*.mywebsite.com    111.1.1.2
```

and a CNAME setup as follows...

```
beta.mywebsite.com 111.1.1.3
```

Would pinging beta.mywebsite.com resolve to 111.1.1.2 or 111.1.1.3? How long does it take to refresh after changing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a CNAME must point to an hostname not an IP address: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

This is still confusing because it doesn't answer the title of the post. It just points out that a CNAME must point to a hostname.

Further, a record with the specific name requested will always override a wildcard or default record.

Comment: Ah! That explains everything :)

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be mixing two things:

1. As @Irosa says, a CNAME must point to a domain name, not an IP address
2. With *wildcard* records, a more specific entry will always override the wildcard entry.

Furthermore, you can't have a `CNAME` and other resource records at the *same* name.

Comment: You can have an MX record pointing at the same name as a CNAME record.

Comment: @dunxd you can, although that used to be considered a configuration failure.

Comment: Are you talking about not *pointing* an MX record at a CNAME record (e.g. `mail MX cname; cname CNAME a-record; a-record A 12.12.12.12`)?  That won't work.  But you could have `mail MX a-record` and `cname CNAME a-record` - that isn't broken.

Comment: @dunxd I meant the former, but it _is_ permitted since RFC 2821.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer - I thought you meant the latter and was responding to that.